# Submit, Update and Delete using form, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am new to PHP and MySQL. 
Trying to build a simple form with insert, update, delete functions.

Adding and retrieving information to and from the database is working fine. But when i want to update an existing row, it does not work.

What am i doing wrong?

I have an index.php and an resultaat.php. The form goes to resultaat.php and returns to index.php directly.

Index.php:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "localdb";
$database = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connectie met SQL mislukt: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql2 = "SELECT ID, naam, achternaam, email FROM nieuw";
$result = $conn->query($sql2);


$formulier = "";
$formulier .= "<form method='post' action='resultaat.php'>\n";
$formulier .= "<fieldset>\n";
$formulier .= "<label>Naam</label>\n";
$formulier .= "<input type='text' name='naam'/>\n <br />";
$formulier .= "<label>Achternaam</label>\n";
$formulier .= "<input type='text' name='achternaam'/><br /> \n";
$formulier .= "<label>Email</label>\n";
$formulier .= "<input type='text' name='email'/><br /> \n";
$formulier .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='bevestigen'/>";
$formulier .= "</fieldset>\n";
$formulier .= "</form>";

echo $formulier;

print <<< HERE
<form method='post' action='resultaat.php'>
<table border="1">

<tr>
    <th hidden></th>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Achternaam</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>

</tr>

HERE;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td hidden name='record' value='$row[ID]'>$row[ID]</td>\n";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='naam' value='$row[naam]'</td>\n";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='achternaam' value='$row[achternaam]'</td>\n";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='email' value='$row[email]'</td>\n";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='Add' onclick='return confirm(\'Weet je zeker dat je dit item wilt bijwerken?\')/>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Niets te tonen";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='add'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>"



?>
```

resultaat.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "localdb";
$database = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connectie met SQL mislukt: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$naam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['naam']);
$achternaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['achternaam']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $naam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['naam']);
    $achternaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['achternaam']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO nieuw (naam, achternaam, email) VALUES ('$naam', '$achternaam', '$email')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

        echo "Gegevens zijn verwerkt.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Aanvraag kon niet verwerkt worden $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    mysqli_close($link);

    header("Location: index.php"); // redirect back to your contact form
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['record'];
    $naam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['naam']);
    $achternaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['achternaam']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']);


    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE nieuw SET naam = '$naam', achternaam = '$achternaam', email = '$email' WHERE ID='$id'";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery)){

        echo "Gegevens zijn verwerkt.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Aanvraag kon niet verwerkt worden $UpdateQuery. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }


    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: No errors appearing?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: I don't get any errors. i receive the message "succesfully added", but that is not true. i think the problem is the id field but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is not in a field. So `$_POST['record'];` is empty.
Use for your id field

```
    echo "<td><Input type='hidden' name='record' value='$row[ID]'>$row[ID]</td>\n";
```

Also you Need one `form` per row for update if not the id will be overridden

Comment: When i echo the $updateQuery it says: UPDATE nieuw SET naam = 'test', achternaam = 'test', email = 'test' WHERE ID='71'

This is also weird. it pulls the second row instead of the first row that i want to update.

Comment: @Sergio sorry can not get you. The update is after the Change i suggested?

Comment: sorry if am not clear. 

When i click on "update" it goes to resultaat.php. In resultaat.php i echo the query and the result is as shown in my previous answer. The id is coming trough the request. 

What i don't understand, instead of the row i want to update, he picks up the ID of the last row i added and that ID is 71. If i add a new row (which will be id 72) and try to update row with ID 71, it behaves the same and picks up ID 72 and tries to update id 72 instead of 71.

Comment: @Sergio Can you check please if all rows in the list has the same id?

Comment: @Sergio Have you checked it in your HTML?

Comment: <tr>
<td><Input type='hidden' name='record' value='71'>71</td>
<td><Input type='hidden' name='record' value='72'>72</td>

everything seems fine.

Comment: Your `form`tag is arround all lines, so the id will be overridden. You need one form per line

Comment: hero! You saved me :) Thank you very much. Can you explain a little bit why it has to be done like that? Or can i read this on a website somewhere?

Comment: @Sergio, if you submit your form all fields will be transfered to Server side as key value pair. So if you have your id/Name twice, How it should be handled? If you send your form via `get` method you can see what is Happening by reading the url

Comment: thank you very much again. I appreciate your help and making some time to give me the right answer. Have a nice day.